# MongoDB Geosptial Query with Distance in Ruby Route

Tags: ruby, mongodb, collections, sinatra, geospatial

I am trying to add a maxDistance filter to my collection query, but it will return nothing anytime I apply the filter. If I don't apply maxDistance, the full collection does come.

What I ultimately want is to return the locations within the distance provided from the coordinates provided, along with returning that integer-based distance from each other within the bson object.

Any help greatly appreciated!

```html
//Find method
@stores =[]
collection.find({
  "location" => {
    "$near" => {
        "$geometry" => {
          "type" =>'Point',
          "coordinates" => [1,1]
        },
        "$maxDistance" => 5000 
        // if deleted will return full collection
    }
  }
}).each do |doc|
      @stores.push(doc)
    end
 
 //collection index 
     @grid = collection.indexes.create_one({ "collection" => "2dsphere"})
     
// collection sample
collection.insert_one({
      :id => 3,
      :rid => "tango",
      :location => [18, 15]
    })
```